# Using dataclass with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to weigh the benefits of using a dataclass when inheriting from a tkinter widget. The issue is: I'm not able to actually inherit a tkinter button properly using a dataclass.

Here is how I would normally inherit from a ttk button (this works perfectly).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk    


class CustomButton(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, master, button_name, new_colour, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        
        self.new_colour = new_colour
        self.button_name = button_name
        
        self.s = ttk.Style(self)
        self.s.configure(f"{button_name}.TButton", background=new_colour)
        
        self.configure(style=f"{button_name}.TButton")


root = tk.Tk()

button1 = CustomButton(root, text="OK", button_name="warning_button", new_colour="red")
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

My attempt to get the same class working as a dataclass is the following (this gives me the error: *builtins.TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'*)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk    
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class CustomButton(ttk.Button):
    
    new_colour: str
    button_name: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.s = ttk.Style(self)
        self.s.configure(f"{self.button_name}.TButton", background=self.new_colour)
        
        self.configure(style=f"{self.button_name}.TButton")


root = tk.Tk()

button1 = CustomButton(root, text="OK", button_name="warning_button", new_colour="red")
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

My main question is: how can I make the above dataclass work just like the first traditional class? What am I doing wrong with the dataclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll try my best to answer this question though I'm fairly new to this dataclass feature. Also, feel free to correct me in any way.*

There are few issues with your dataclass.

1. The error message speaks for itself. As there is no field `text` in your dataclass, but even if you add a field `text` it will raise the same error for the "root" argument passed to it. **So the right field is not there.**
2. **You are not passing anything to the Button.** You need to pass arguments to `super().__init__(...)`, passing anything to `super().__init__` means passing to the inherited class's `__init__()`. So `root` and `text` should be passed as arguments to `super().__init__()`
3. Also, you need to make `root` and `text` fields an *[InitVar fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables)* so they can be passed as arguments to the `__post__init__()` method. It is not necessary to create them InitVar fields, they will work just fine as normal fields but I think that's how it should be done.

*Correct Example:*

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from dataclasses import dataclass, InitVar


@dataclass
class CustomButton(ttk.Button):

    master: InitVar[tk.Tk]
    text: InitVar[str]
    new_colour: str
    button_name: str

    def __post_init__(self, master, text):
        super().__init__(master=master, text=text)
        self.s = ttk.Style(self)
        self.s.configure(f"{self.button_name}.TButton",
                         background=self.new_colour)
        self.configure(style=f"{self.button_name}.TButton")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    button1 = CustomButton(
        root, text='Hello', button_name="warning_button", new_colour="red")
    button1.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```